# What does 'natural boundary' mean?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What does 'natural boundary' mean? Like when we say a brownian motion's left boundary is absorbing and right boundary is natural?

Comment: This probably refers to natural boundary *conditions*, see [Boundary conditions for the Fokker-Planck equation](http://www3.ul.ie/gleesonj/Papers/SDEs/AM4062_notes6.pdf), "natural boundary" is something unrelated from complex analysis.

Comment: thanks, that helps